# How do I remove quotation from csv?

Tags: php, laravel, csv

How do I remove quotation from csv?

## Code

```
use Goutte\Client;

$client = new Client();

$response = $client->request('GET', 'http://c-manage.herokuapp.com/login');
$login_form = $response->filter('form')->form();
$login_form["account"] = '1';
$login_form["password"] = 'rpa1001';
$client->submit($login_form);
$client->request('GET', 'http://c-manage.herokuapp.com/client/download?searchQuery%5Bstatus%5D=1&searchQuery%5BregisterStartDate%5D=2010-01-01&searchQuery%5BregisterEndDate%5D=2020-01-01');
$csvResponse = $client->getResponse()->getContent();
return $csvResponse;
```

response is ...

```
ID,ステータス,分類,名前,名前（カナ）,誕生日,郵便番号,住所,メールアドレス,電話番号,FAX,メモ,登録日,更新日\r\n                                                                     
213,契約中,個人,"鶴田 秀夫","ツルタ ヒデオ",2000/07/24,1508207,神奈川県吉田市北区佐々木町小林7-4-5,hiroshi.nakatsugawa@yamaguchi.net,0310-282-609,0730-327-581,,"2010-01-25 00:00:
00","2010-01-25 00:00:00"\r\n                                                                                                                                                     
221,契約中,個人,"桑原 彩羅","クワハラ サイラ",2008/04/03,8103797,青森県杉山市西区石田町浜田3-4-10,vwakamatsu@kiriyama.jp,090-5710-4350,03849-5-5746,,"2010-01-09 00:00:00","2010-0
1-09 00:00:00"\r\n                                                                                                                                                                
237,契約中,個人,"堤 悟志","ツツミ サトシ",2001/04/29,6875750,栃木県佐々木市東区中島町浜田6-6-6,xtsuda@suzuki.com,022-557-4260,0573-01-2822,,"2010-02-07 00:00:00","2010-02-07 00:0
0:00"\r\n                                                                                                                                                                         
273,契約中,個人,"富永 圭三","トミナガ ケイゾウ",2003/03/16,6314524,静岡県若松市東区廣川町青山10-9-6,yamaguchi.takuma@kondo.com,0020-062-493,06-3862-0779,,"2010-02-13 00:00:00","2
010-02-13 00:00:00"\r\n 
.
.
.
```

## What I want to do

I want to remove quotation from csv.

not

```
213,契約中,個人,"鶴田 秀夫","ツルタ ヒデオ",2000/07/24,1508207,
```

but

```
213,契約中,個人,鶴田 秀夫,ツルタ ヒデオ,2000/07/24,1508207,
```

※This personal information is fake.

## What I did

1. str_replace(""", "", $csvResponse);
2. str_replace("\xEF\xBB\xBF", '', $csvResponse);

but, not working

Comment: Do you assign the return of `str_replace` to anything? If you use double quotes for encapsulation you have to escape the double quote inside. Alternatively, and probably easier to read, you can use single quotes for encapsulation, `str_replace('"', "", $csvResponse);`. Use error reporting, that caused an error as it was written.

Comment: You shouldn't remove the the quotations. They serve a purpose there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotes serve a purpose here so you shouldn't be removing them haphazardly. The quotes prevent columns from breaking when they need to contain text that can also contain the delimiter. Like `"Foo, bar, baz"` for example. Removing the quotes turns this one column into 3 columns, which is obviously wrong.

Though, if you did want to remove them `str_replace` would certainly **not** be the way to go, because the quotes can be escaped to be literals inside the column. For example, using `str_replace` on this column: `"He said \"this is crazy\", and left."` would strip literals from the column value.

Instead you should load the CSV data with `fgetcsv()` or `str_getcsv()` and rebuild the CSV without the quotes like so...

```
foreach (str_getcsv($csvData) as $row) {
    echo implode(",", $row), "\n";
}
```

This will give you back the literal values of each row without the quotes. Though any literal quotes inside those values will become quotes.